# Way to have vim warn when file grows larger than desired maximum?

Tags: vim

I'm interested in having vim provide some obvious indication when a *.rb file becomes longer than some upper limit such as 120 lines (at load or during edit)

Does anyone know if any built-in vim facility or existing vim plugin does this? If not, then does anyone have advice on how to approach writing a vim script to do that?

=====

Here's what I ended up doing (per @benjifisher) ...

```
augroup TooMuchRuby
  au! BufRead,CursorHold *.rb
        \ if line("$") > 120 | echohl WarningMsg | echo 'Too Much Ruby' | echohl NONE | endif
augroup END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need a couple of autocommands.  For example,

```
augroup TooMuchRuby
  au! BufRead,CursorHold *.rb
        \ if line("$") > 120 | echoerr 'Too Much Ruby!' | endif
augroup END
```

If `:echoerr` is too much, you could use `echohl WarningMsg | echo 'Too Much Ruby' | echohl NONE`.

Comment: Well, it could be nicer, but it does work, se Th very much. The `:echoerr` is definitely too much, but the warning is pretty nice. Would be better if it could somehow clear itself when the line count drops back down, though it does get cleared after the next ":" command or search.